# Minecraft Error; 'Sorry, but we couldn't connect to our servers'

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

On my Minecraft, Linux Version, whenever I try to login to the launcher, I get an error.
`Sorry, but we couldn't connect to our servers. ( IllegalStateException: ).`

Comment: This does not have an answer on another post

Answer (score 4):

This error message appears when Minecraft cannot connect to the internet. Check your network connection and your firewall/antivirus settings.

It can also sometimes happen when the Mojang servers are offline. In that case you just have to wait a few minutes and then try again.

Comment: It works on my mac, but not on my laptop.

Comment: Then look at the differences between the two. Like network connection, firewall, etc.